# Unable to find exact filename using Ansible's find module

Tags: text, ansible, find

I'm able to find `modules.jar` under `/app` directory as evident by the below output:

```
 find /app -name modules.jar 2>/dev/null

/app/axmw/TEST/jboss-eap-7.2.5.CP/misc/modules.jar
/app/jboss/modules.jar
```

As you can see we find two file results.

Note: i need the exact match for file `modules.jar`

However,  when i use ansible find module to search for the same zero matches are found.

```
  tasks:

    - name: Debug check if Profile Path or server name are valid by checking PATH
      find:
        paths: /app
        file_type: file
        patterns: 'modules.jar'
        excludes: 'log,tmp,.installation'
      tags: always
      register: jarfound

    - name: Number of modules.jar found under /app
      debug:
        msg: "{{ jarfound.matched }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [Debug check if Profile Path or server name are valid by checking PATH] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [10.9.156.126]

TASK [Number of modules.jar found under /app] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.9.156.126] => {
    "msg": "0"
}
```

I tried the below patterns as well but everytime i get matched as "0"

Can you please explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing ***recurse*** directive in your task parameter list. As documented in [find module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html), default value for this parameter is `no` hence the reason for you not able to find the file which is under sub-directories of top-level `/app` path. Just add `recurse` as shown below to find the file:

```
  tasks:

    - name: Debug check if Profile Path or server name are valid by checking PATH
      find:
        paths: /app
        file_type: file
        recurse: yes
        patterns: 'modules.jar'
        excludes: 'log,tmp,.installation'
      tags: always
      register: jarfound

    - name: Number of modules.jar found under /app
      debug:
        msg: "{{ jarfound.matched }}"
```

**[Update]** Looking at last comment (regarding ignoring `.installation` folder), the `excludes` parameter is applicable only for ***basename*** of the item (excerpt from documentation - *Items whose basenames match an excludes pattern are culled from patterns matches*). Thus `excludes` is not going to work for this scenario.

You have following options to get what you want. You can use either of these options as per suitability and applicability in your scenario.

1. I noticed that the name of the file under `.installation` folder is *misc.modules.jar* thus you can simply exclude it if you switch to regex instead of current globs(shell) pattern. For this to work, add `use_regex: yes` and change your pattern to `modules\\.jar` to make it very explicit for this filename. This will work since regex, unlike shell patterns, are required to match **ENTIRE file name, not just parts of it**
2. Use find twice, first with `file_type: directory` where you can exclude 'log,tmp,.installation' as normal and get all other directories. `excludes` will work this time since you are searching for folders and basename of each folder will be matched against this `excludes`. Use the registered o/p from this task as `path` in following `find` task searching for the filename. I'll still recommend to use regex in second find to further restrict the search to entire file name.
3. Post process the registered o/p from `find` task and filter out those elements from list which have the folder you want to be explicitly removed. Take a look at [Jinja2 filter list using string contains test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281785/jinja2-filter-list-using-string-contains-test) which has multiple solutions for this purpose.

Comment: If i give `recurse: yes` i get output of files containing `.installation` folder which i had excluded like below:

`"msg": "multiple JARs found at /app/jboss/.installation/patches/misc.modules.jar"`

Can you please suggest?

Comment: Updated the answer with solutions to address ignoring intermediate folders.